# How to create index in MySQL JSON object arrays?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, indexing

I known how to create index in MySQL JSON object and how to search data in JSON object array. However, I want to know how to create an index in a JSON object arrays.

Such as I have a table like this, and `addresses` is a JSON object array.

```sql
create table if not exists `json_test`
(
    id int auto_increment primary key ,
    addresses json null comment '[{cityId,name}]',
)
```

The following statement works fine, but every rows will be searched in the table, it is really terrible.

```sql
explain
select * from json_test jt join json_table(
    jt.addresses,
    '$[*]'
    columns (
        `id` for ordinality ,
        `cid` int path '$.cityId'
        )
    ) addrs where addrs.cid=1;
```

How do I create an index in a JSON array type such as on `jt.addresses.cityId`?